# How to receive emails from postfix in a Python script?

Tags: python, email, postfix-mta

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/258491/208727) gives details about how to route all incoming emails, i.e. emails arriving to my server's Postfix, to a Python script. But then it seems that the emails will be routed to `stdin`, unparsed.

How to listen to emails in Python in this way (i.e. `postfix ---> python`), and extract useful data, such as `from`, `to`, `subject`, etc.?

Is there something like:

```
while True:
    mail = waitForNewMailFromPostfix()
    subject = mail.getSubject()
    from = mail.getFrom()
    body = mail.getBody()
    # do something with it!
```

Comment: Once you're getting Postfix to pass you an email on stdin, the hard part is done. See the [`email.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html) documentation for the rest.

Comment: It's not 100% finished, but I hope that following https://serverfault.com/a/258491/208727 it will eventually work :) Have you tried it before?

Comment: I have configured Postfix to pass emails to a python script, yes. I use it to allow texting in of information for applications. I didn't follow those instructions in particular, but the process was pretty much the same.

Comment: @glibdud Did it also require *all* these steps? It seems quite complicated there, I would be happy with a workflow using less steps... If you have one please post an answer, would be great :)

Comment: Basically, yes. Postfix is a complicated beast.